# Android: Trigger redraw after a colour change

Tags: android, view, redraw

I am currently working on a Connect four game.

My game works by the user pressing the 'New game' button. This then draws 42 (7*6) green circles to screen. These circles are used to represent holes on the connect four board i.e. green circles currently do not contain a player's token/counter

At this moment in time I am working on adding the tokens/counters. I have got code working (to a certain point) that enables the user to pick a column. Using log.d() It seems that I am successful changing the colour value of the gaps. My problem is that I do not know how to send this changing in colour to the View i.e. so the gap actually changes from green to red (player's token colour).

How can I send a request to the View so the gap is re-drawn?

N.B. Sorry for the lack of code but it is currently messy and not fully working. 
The View is controlled by a ConnectFourView.java (View), the game screen is Board.java (Model) and the code that works out which column has been selected Gaps.java (controller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `invalidate()` on your view and it will be redrawn

Comment: just reading about invalidate() now. I am not 100% on how it works. I believe the invalidate() only works in the View (so my case this would be ConnectFourView.java) How would I send the request from Gaps.java (where the change of colour value is done) to the View?

Comment: I think Gaps instance has a reference to ConnectFourView, hasn't it?

Comment: It does. I have tried connectfourview.invalidate(); in the Gaps.java class after the change of the colour value. returns an error

Comment: got the invalidate() working now. had small v instead of V. So that is working. Application is now running but when it getting a java null pointer exception. Progress at least. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, a call to [`invalidate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#invalidate()) should be done from the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(() -> view.invalidate());
```

or

```
view.postInvalidate();
```

Also note that redrawing a container might not redraw all of its views. In my case I was invalidating a container (a `ConstraintLayout`) but the view inside it didn't get redrawn until I called `postInvalidate()` (from a service thread) directly on the view.