# Using invalidate() , java.lang.NullPointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, invalidation

I am currently working on a Connect four game

I have managed to develop the app to point to where the game knows what column the user has selected. I am currently trying to change the colour of the gap to the respective colour of the user (token has been placed).

The problem I am having is when connectfourView.invalidate() is called I get a java.lang.NullPointerexception

Code below

```
public void tokenPlacement (int index, float xpos) {
        int x = 0;
        int lowerxpos = (int) (xpos - 10);
        int higherxpos = (int) (xpos + 10);

        while (x <= 6)
        {
        if ( lowerxpos <= ((float) (columnselects.get(x).getWidthPos())) && higherxpos >= ((float) (columnselects.get(x).getWidthPos())))
        {
            Log.d("In IF", Float.toString(x));
            Log.d("Looking at the colour", Float.toString(gaps.get(x).getColor()));
            gaps.get(x).setColor(-1);
            Log.d("After change what is the colour now", Float.toString(gaps.get(x).getColor()));
            connectfourView.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        x++;
        }
        }
```

About the code. Firstly I know this will only affect the bottom layer of each column's gaps. I will fix this when the colour changing is working. This code is from Gaps.java. This view is ConnectFourView.java (instance connectfourView) where the gaps are drawn to screen. All gaps are stored in a list (gaps) and are defined in the Gap.java (x-postion, colour etc.)

Section from Gap.java

```
    public Gap (int j, int i, int color, double diameter, double widthpos, double heightpos){
        this.j = j;
        this.i = i;
        this.color = color;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.widthpos = widthpos;
        this.heightpos = heightpos;
    }

    public int getJ() {return j;}

    public int getI() {return i;}

    public int getColor() {return color;}

    public void setColor(int newColor) {this.color = newColor;}

    public double getDiameter() {return diameter;}

    public double getWidthPos() {return widthpos;}

    public double getHeightPos() {return heightpos;}
}
```

This is a question I asked to get to this [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172914/android-trigger-redraw-after-a-colour-change)

Note that the gaps are added with a button press 'New Game'

If any other information or code is need please leave a comment

Added for dmon:

This is where connectfourView is defined, it has also been imported

```
public class Gaps {

    ConnectFourView connectfourView;

/* Other code, not related to question */

public void tokenplacement()//at bottom of class Gaps
```

I have noticed that when a click the exit button on the screen all the gaps do change color just before the main menu is loaded, so the problem is just trying to refresh the screen

From ConnectFourView.java

```
public ConnectFourView(Context context, Gaps gaps) {
        super(context);
        this.gaps = gaps;
        setFocusable(true);
    }

//used to mange the attributes of the board (different colour to background for board)
    public ConnectFourView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Gaps gaps) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.gaps = gaps;
        setFocusable(true);
        setMinimumWidth(getWidth());
        setMinimumHeight(getHeight());
    }
```

link to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3aym85i0c4hkbjt/Connectfourapp.zip)

Comment: Are you sure that `connectfourView` is not `null`? Have you tried it in the debugger?

Comment: I am not 100% about using the debugger. If it helps I did state at the in the class 'ConnectFourView connectfourView'. Could it do with the fact that the gaps are added by a button 'New Game' (just added this information to the question. @Henry

Comment: Show us where you defined the `connectFourView` variable.

Comment: @dmon I have added where connectfourView is defined, Looking into it a bit more I do think Henry could be correct

Answer (score 0):

As others have said (I gave Henry the bump), connectfourView has to be null there.  You need to initialize it:

```
ConnectFourView connectfourView = new ConnectFourView();
```

I don't see where that is ever done so it's likely set to null by default.

Comment: when I add this to the Gaps class, it has conflicts with ConnectFourView.java (View)

Comment: Confused by your statement.  What are the compile errors?  Can we see a complete listing of your code?

Comment: Once added I get the error The constructor ConnectFourView() is undefined. it then has five quick fixes; 1 Add arguments to match ConnectFourView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Gaps gaps) , 2 Add arguments to match ConnectFourView(Context context, Gaps gaps). 3 and 4 is to remove these from ConnectFourView 5 is creating a contruster. I will add my ConnectFourView.java code and a link to the project files from dropbox

Comment: Okay, so you have no null constructor for ConnectForView, that's fine.  So you need to construct your ConnectFourView in your activity where you have a Context.  ConnectFourView connectfourView = new ConnectFourView(getContext(), myGaps).  I think you need to relook at your design.  Your ConnectFourView object needs Gaps and your Gaps object needs ConnectFourView.

Comment: I think a better design would be for your Gaps guy to post an event to a message handler and have your activity process that event.  Then the main activity can call invalidate on the ConnectFourView object.